LevelDB error: plyvel._plyvel.Error: NotFound: c:/tmp/testdb/LOCK: The system cannot find the path specified
I followed this answer on how to install LevelDB on Windows. Everything went smoothly. The only thing I didn't know how to do (and if I had to it anyway) is step 1.2. Also I didn't do this part: set PYTHONLIB=<full path to plyvel>.
Now when I try to run this simple script:
import plyvel
db = plyvel.DB('c:/tmp/testdb/', create_if_missing=True)

...I get this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programi\proba\proba.py", line 3, in <module>
    db = plyvel.DB('c:/tmp/testdb/', create_if_missing=True)
  File "plyvel\_plyvel.pyx", line 247, in plyvel._plyvel.DB.__init__
  File "plyvel\_plyvel.pyx", line 94, in plyvel._plyvel.raise_for_status
plyvel._plyvel.Error: b'NotFound: c:/tmp/testdb//LOCK: The system cannot find the path specified.\r\n'

I tried removing trailing /, changing path, creating folders before calling script, removing argument create_if_missing but to no avail.
I'm using python 3.9.

Ok, this worked for me, honestly don't know why and I can't reproduce problem anymore. Try passing empty string as path or dot (.) and if it creates some files, delete them and try with original path you wanted.
Since I had a lot of problems while setting up LevelDB on Windows. I will share short manual on how to set up LevelDB. Manual is heavily reliant on answer I linked in question but I added some steps that are needed for it to work and some fixes to potential errors some may find on the way.
Tested on: Python 3.9, Visual Studio 2019
Setup
Download CMake from: https://cmake.org/download/ and install it.
Download and install Cython: python -m pip install Cython.
Download and install package setuptools: python -m pip install setuptools (needed for nmake to work).
Set env variables for tools:

Set system variable for CMake (under path variable) to bin folder (it's where you installed CMake): C:\Program Files\CMake\bin
Set user variable for devenv (under path variable) to IDE folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE
Set user variable for nmake (under path variable): C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\Hostx64\x64
To check if Cython command is available, start cmd and execute command cython --version. If it says that command is not recognizable, you have to add env variable.
First check if cython.exe file exists in Scripts folder in folder where your Python is installed (for example: C:/Users/MMDE Laptop/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/Scripts). If it exists, add path to Scripts folder in user variable (under path variable).
If it doesn't exist, try setting user variable (under path variable) to site-packages folder from folder where your Python is installed (for example: C:/Users/MMDE Laptop/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/Lib/site-packages). In that folder, you will probably find Cython folder and cython.py file.

Restart all cmd windows.
Build LevelDB

Clone LevelDB: git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/google/leveldb.git
Make folder named build and switch to it (mkdir build, cd build).
Use CMake: cmake -G "Visual Studio 16" ..
Use devenv: devenv /build Release leveldb.sln
This will create leveldb.lib  under leveldb/build/Release/. Save path to leveldb folder (for example: D:/Programi/proba/leveldb).

Build Plyvel

Clone Plyvel: git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/wbolster/plyvel
Modify setup.py:
Change extra_compile_args: extra_compile_args = ['-Wall', '-g', '-x', 'c++', '-std=c++11', '-I<insert saved path>/include']. It should look like this: extra_compile_args =  ['-Wall', '-g', '-x', 'c++', '-std=c++11', '-ID:/Programi/proba/leveldb/include'] (notice that there is not space between -I and D).
Change ext_modules:

ext_modules = [
    Extension(
        "plyvel._plyvel",
        sources=["plyvel/_plyvel.cpp", "plyvel/comparator.cpp"],
        libraries=["leveldb"],
        extra_compile_args=extra_compile_args,
        # add library_dirs (path to folder containing leveldb.lib that was created earlier)
        library_dirs=["D:/Programi/proba/leveldb/build/Release"],
    )
]


Use nmake in plyvel folder like this: nmake all . It may require to start cmd as administrator.

Test
import plyvel

db = plyvel.DB('./tmp', create_if_missing=True)
db.put(b'key', b'value')
value = db.get(b'key')
print(value) # b'value'

If you get this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programi\proba\proba.py", line 3, in <module>
    db = plyvel.DB('c:/tmp/testdb/', create_if_missing=True)
  File "plyvel\_plyvel.pyx", line 247, in plyvel._plyvel.DB.__init__
  File "plyvel\_plyvel.pyx", line 94, in plyvel._plyvel.raise_for_status
plyvel._plyvel.Error: b'NotFound: .tmp/LOCK: The system cannot find the path specified.\r\n'

Try passing empty string as path or dot (.) and if it creates some files, delete them and try with original path you wanted.
Using with virtualenv

Activate virtual environment
Position cmd in folder where is setup.py
Execute python setup.py install (it should show plyvel in pip list)

